# SFINAE with boost enable if

Tags: c++, templates, boost, sfinae, enable-if

I am trying to implement a templated pair class that uses sfinae to distinguish between array and non-array types. So far, I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class pair
{
public:

   //default constructors. one for non-array types and one for arrays. These work.
   template <typename temp_type = T>
   pair(typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_array<temp_type>>::type* ignore = 0)
      : first(T())
      , second(T())
   {}

   template <typename temp_type = T>
   pair(typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_array<temp_type>>::type* ignore = 0)
   {}

   //assignment operator attempts for non-array types (not in code at same time.) These don't work.
   template<typename temp_type = T> 
   pair<temp_type>& operator=(pair<typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_array<temp_type>>::type>                const& rhs)
   {
       this->first = rhs.first;
       this->second = rhs.second;
       return *this;
   }

   template<typename temp_type = T> 
   auto operator=(pair<temp_type> const& rhs) -> pair<typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_array<temp_type>>::type>&
   {
       this->first = rhs.first;
       this->second = rhs.second;
       return *this;
   }

   T first;
   T second;
};
```

The first attempt at the assignment operator fails with an "illegal use of type void" error. The second compiles, but when I debug, MSVC tells me that "no executable code is associated with that line." I am using the MSVC 12 64 bit compiler.

If you could offer any insight as to what is wrong here, that would be very helpful.

Also, just a few observations I've made about sfinae in c++ (that may be right or wrong):

- sfinae requires the member function to be templated but it cannot use the class template type(s) for this purpose. Why?
- sfinae can be done by only modifying the template parameters and not the return type or inputs. How, exactly does this work. What's the flexibility of this method?

I know this is long winded and references topics covered in numerous other posts, but I haven't been able to put those explanations together in a way that concisely explains sfinae in c++.

Some posts I've read:

[Explain C++ SFINAE to a non-C++ programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407633/explain-c-sfinae-to-a-non-c-programmer/3408317#3408317) (high level intro)

[Select class constructor using enable_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842478/select-class-constructor-using-enable-if) (sfinae for constructors)

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

I have modified my code based on the comments below and I still can't get this to work as expected (The compiler is not even seeing the source.) It's an interesting situation because the example is completely contrived and the default assignment operator actually works in this scenario. Nevertheless, I don't think the compiler should be overriding my attempt to overload the operator.

I have tried the following 4 methods and none of them seem to be built into the executable:

```
template<typename temp_type = T> 
pair<temp_type>& operator=(pair<typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_array<temp_type>, temp_type>::type> const& rhs)

{
        this->first = rhs.first;
        this->second = rhs.second;
        return *this;
}

template<typename temp_type = T>
auto operator=(pair<temp_type> const& rhs) -> pair<typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_array<temp_type>, temp_type>::type>&
{
    this->first = rhs.first;
    this->second = rhs.second;
    return *this;
}

template<typename ret_type = boost::disable_if<boost::is_array<T>, T>::type, typename = void>
pair<ret_type>& operator=(pair<ret_type> const& rhs)
{
    this->first = rhs.first;
    this->second = rhs.second;
    return *this;
}

template<typename temp_type = T, typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_array<temp_type>, temp_type>::type = 0>
pair<T>& operator=(pair<temp_type> const& rhs)
{
    this->first = rhs.first;
    this->second = rhs.second;
    return *this;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: start with adding `typename` for dependent names in constructors

Comment: `typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_array<temp_type>>::type` is `void` if substitution succeeds. You need to provide the type - e.g., `typename boost::disable_if<boost::is_array<temp_type>, temp_type>::type`.

Comment: @PiotrS. sorry, I forgot that when was transcribing to stack overflow. Still having issues with the assignment ops.

Comment: @mgoldman what issue?

Comment: @PiotrS. I have edited my post with my current effort.

Comment: The problem is that default assignment operator is still part of the overload (and is a exact match).

Comment: What's your test code look like?  Are you sure you are using your `pair` and not `std::pair`?  Are you doing something where the copy assignment or move assignment operator will not be used?

Comment: @Jarod42: I assume you mean copy assignment operator?

Comment: @BenVoigt: yes, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget, converting assignment can be implemented by template functions, but copy and move assignment operators can't.

> A user-declared copy  assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static **non-template** member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`.
>
> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy assignment operator, one is declared implicitly.  If the class definition declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy assignment  operator  is  defined  as  deleted;  otherwise,  it  is  defined  as  defaulted
>
> A user-declared move assignment operator `X::operator=` is a non-static **non-template** member function of class `X` with exactly one parameter of type `X&&`, `const X&&`, `volatile X&&`, or `const volatile X&&`.

and the note

> Because  a  template  assignment  operator  or  an  assignment  operator  taking  an  rvalue  reference  parameter  is  never  a copy  assignment  operator,  the  presence  of  such  an  assignment  operator  does  not  suppress  the  implicit  declaration  of  a  copy assignment operator.  Such assignment operators participate in overload resolution with other assignment operators, including copy assignment operators, and, if selected, will be used to assign an object.

(above quotes found in section 12.8, wording from draft n3936)

Comment: Thanks Ben. Can you clarify how the compiler determines which overloaded function to call. I may be misinterpreting the std, but it seems like my assignment operator should still be considered in the overload set? If so, any ideas as to why it is not being chosen?

Comment: @mgoldman: All other things equal, a non-template is chosen before a template function.  13.3.3. has a rule about "a viable function F1 is deﬁned to be a better function than another viable function
F2 if .... F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization"

Answer (score 1):

Why your attempts fail to work is explained in [@BenVoigt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26305603/3953764) 's answer, here is only an alternative solution. You can dispatch the `operator=` call to an appropriate overload depending on the type your template was instantiated with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template <typename T>
class pair
{    
public:    
    pair& operator=(pair const& rhs)
    {
        return assign(rhs, boost::is_array<T>());
    }

private:
    pair& assign(pair const&, boost::true_type)
    {
        std::cout << "array" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }

    pair& assign(pair const&, boost::false_type)
    {
        std::cout << "not array" << std::endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    pair<int> a, b;
    b = a;

    pair<int[]> c, d;
    c = d;
}
```

Output:

```
not array
array
```

And you can do the same with constructors, delegating (C++11) the call to another one:

```
pair() : pair(boost::is_array<T>()) {}

pair(boost::true_type) { /*initialize array pair*/ }

pair(boost::false_type) { /*initialize non-array pair*/ }
```

Code looks cleaner and you don't have to compete with the compiler on *whose `operator=` better matches the actual argument*.

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ec5c34c0c99ed54)