# How to make a C++ constructor participate in overload resolution only in certain conditions?

Tags: c++

For example, for a template class `Test<T>`, I want to make its move constructor only participate in overload resolution when `T` is void or is move constructible.

And I do know that defining `Test(Test&&)` as deleted does not prevent it to participate in overload resolution.

Comment: Show us the actual usecase/code. Looks like [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: What is the actual problem you need to solve. Usually you don't need to do these kind of things. There might be other ways to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: Showing specific problems or examples may help you solve them better.

Comment: A lot of questions already answer this - have you tried e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842478/select-class-constructor-using-enable-if ?  If you agree that is your question, we should close this as a duplicate....

Comment: Actually I don't have an actual problem, cause I just read this post on cppreference (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected/expected), and it says the move constructor only participate in overload resolution when T is void or T is move constructible, so I just wondered how to achieve that? @user12002570

Comment: _"so I just wondered how to achieve that?"_ — You can simply check the source code of some implementation, such as: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/1fad78b123d20db675d339053e4265aceb07c4af/libcxx/include/__expected/expected.h#L139, https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/1fad78b123d20db675d339053e4265aceb07c4af/libcxx/include/__expected/expected.h#L144, https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/2e51fff7ce02a6105aa1acff57cbbdd8a767a33f/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/expected#L395, etc. In general, you can achieve such behavior with either SFINAE or constraints (since C++20).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to c++20 concepts it is very simple

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
class Foo{
    public:
      Foo() = default;
      Foo(const Foo&) 
      {
        std::cout << "copy_ctor \n";
      }
      Foo(Foo&& other) requires std::is_void_v<T> || std::is_move_constructible_v<T>
      {
        std::cout<< "move ctor \n"; 
      } 
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
         << "std::vector<int> is move contructible : " << std::is_move_constructible_v<std::vector<int>> << "\n"
         << "std::atomic<int> is move contructible : " << std::is_move_constructible_v<std::atomic<int>> << "\n";


    //vector<int> is move constructible
    using foo_vect = Foo<std::vector<int>>;
    foo_vect v1;
    foo_vect v2(std::move(v1));
    //atomic int is  not move constructible
    using foo_atom = Foo<std::atomic<int>>;
    foo_atom a1;
    foo_atom a2(std::move(a1));

    using foo_void = Foo<void>;
    foo_void vo1;
    foo_void vo2(std::move(vo1));
    return 0;
}
```

Before C++20 you have to use SFINAE, it may look like that

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T1,typename T2> 
constexpr bool move_ctor_enabled = 
       std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T1>,std::remove_cvref_t<T2>> 
       &&  (std::is_void_v<T2> || std::is_move_constructible_v<T2>); 
       
template<class T>
class Foo{
    public:
      Foo() = default;
      Foo(const Foo&) 
      {
        std::cout << "copy_ctor \n";
      }
      template<class T2, class = std::enable_if_t<move_ctor_enabled<T,T2>>> //(1)
      Foo(Foo<T2>&& other) 
      {
        std::cout<< "move ctor \n"; 
      } 
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha 
         << "std::vector<int> is move contructible : " << std::is_move_constructible_v<std::vector<int>> << "\n"
         << "std::atomic<int> is move contructible : " << std::is_move_constructible_v<std::atomic<int>> << "\n";


    //vector<int> is move constructible
    using foo_vect = Foo<std::vector<int>>;
    foo_vect v1;
    foo_vect v2(std::move(v1));
    //atomic int is  not move constructible
    using foo_atom = Foo<std::atomic<int>>;
    foo_atom a1;
    foo_atom a2(std::move(a1));

    using foo_void = Foo<void>;
    foo_void vo1;
    foo_void vo2(std::move(vo1));
    return 0;
}
```

the compile time constant move_ctor_enabled is true if the move ctor should be enabled and false if the move ctor should not enabled. Here i presuppose that T is the template parameter of the destination Foo , and T2 the template parameter of the object which should be moved Foo. We want only move from object of same type, whichs template parameter is move constructible or void.
We define a template move ctor, the template paramter T2 will determined by type deduction. The unnamed second template type parameter is defaultet with enable_if_t. That expression evaluates to void if its template parameter is true, an produce an error if the valueof its template parameter is false. While the compiler is generating the list of possible matches for the overload resultion, an erroneous signature lead not to an compilation error, but the option is removed from the overload matching list.
It's a mess to think about this enable_if stuff, so I'm glad we now have a clean way to do it.
Both version produce the following output:

```
std::vector<int> is move contructible : true
std::atomic<int> is move contructible : false
move ctor 
copy_ctor 

move ctor
```

Comment: "While the compiler is generating the list of possible matches for the overload resultion, an erroneous signature lead not to an compilation error, but the option is removed from the overload matching list."

Thanks a lot, I do know SFINAE rules, but I readlly didn't know that.